# Balancing multiple wagers on weighted bets

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

**Needed Information:**

**Sum Weighted No:** 9,187

**Sum Weighted Yes:** 8,899

**Current weight:** 83,948 ( from 100,000 to 1 )

```
ID# Side Weight Amount Wagered      

1   Yes  99,997 0.04900000

2   Yes  99,976 0.04000000

3   No   99,976 0.06000000

4   No   98,411 0.03240280
```

Total wagered on Yes : 0.089

Total wagered on No :  0.093240280

These are the 4 wagers made on the proposition.

Winnings for each wager are calculated by the formula:

```
                           .99 * Amount_Wagered * Total_Wagered_on_Losing_Side * Weight

(.99 * Amount_Wagered) + ( ------------------------------------------------------------ )

                                        Sum_Weighted_for_Winning_Side
```

For example if Yes won the amount paid to ID #1 would be:

```
                             .99 * (.049) * (0.093240280) * 99,997

(.99 * (.049)) +         ( ----------------------------------------- )

                                         8,899
```

= 0.099335377 winnings

Problem:
If I hold multiple wagers on the board some of which may be Yes and some No how do I determine the amount to wager given the current weight in order to win the same amount regardless of the outcome.

Key Issue: Whenever a wager is made on one side the amount won for wagers made on the other side increase.